# Basic HTTP authentication proxy?

Tags: linux, arm, http-proxy, privoxy

I'd like to configure my smartphone to use the web filter Privoxy application I left running on a Linux appliance at home, as an easy way to simplify web pages and rid them of ads missed by AdBlockPlus et al.

However, Privoxy doesn't support user authentication, so am thinking of installing some basic HTTP authentication proxy that will take care of this before handing off requests to Privoxy:
[image]

Does someone know of a good solution? FYI, this is for an armv5tel-powered appliance running Debian.

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you can create a VPN connection for the smart phone to use, and then route VPN traffic through Privoxy.  Unless I am misunderstanding the question, I would create a VPN connection on my smartphone and have it route all web traffic through the VPN connection.  You could even have the VPN authenticate through the same server as the HTTP authentication server.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Since the connection doesn't need to be encrypted, I was thinking of a simple HTTP authentication server.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your programming skills.
I'd personally use node.js with http-proxy and an authentication module, etc.
A simpler solution, which won't be as fast but requires less coding and more configuration would be using Apache with mod_proxy.
Let me know if you need more information than that -- good luck!